# Minecraft Fabric Modding, how to get access to private field with help mixin Accessor

Tags: java, minecraft, mixins, minecraft-fabric

i have a problem with Accessor in mixins.

I want to get a private field from the MultiplayerScreen class, for this I use an [Accessor](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:mixin_accessors), but something is going wrong.

**Accessor:**

```java
package ru.flexice.mixin;

import net.minecraft.client.gui.screen.multiplayer.MultiplayerScreen;
import net.minecraft.client.network.ServerInfo;
import org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.Mixin;
import org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.gen.Accessor;

@Mixin(MultiplayerScreen.class)
public interface MultiplayerScreenAccessor {
    @Accessor
    ServerInfo getSelectedEntry();
}
```

**Inject to Code**

```java
@Inject(at = @At("RETURN"), method = "select")
    private void select(CallbackInfo callbackInfo) {
        try {
            Screen s = MinecraftClient.getInstance().currentScreen;
            if (s != null) {
                System.out.println(((MultiplayerScreenAccessor) s).getSelectedEntry().address);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

and i just get

```
Mixin transformation of ru.flexice.mixin.MultiplayerScreenAccessor failed
```

Comment: Another way would be to `@Shadow` the private variable from your Mixin, and use the accessor you made in your interface to pull the value. Only downside to this is you'd need to do `((MultiplayerScreenAccessor) multiplayerScreen).getSelectedEntry()`. I'd give you a better answer about `@Accessor`, but im honestly unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Actually, can you confirm that the name of the private field is `selectedEntry`?

Comment: yes, name of the private field is selectedEntry

Comment: also i can't get multiplayerScreen, i try get it like MinecraftClient.getInstance().currentScreen but it need to cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a @Shadow

```java
@Shadow
private ServerInfo selectedEntry;
```

```java
@Inject(at = @At("TAIL"), method = "select")
    public void select(CallbackInfo callbackInfo) {
        try {
            System.out.println(this.selectedEntry.address);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```